# How does this dictionary comprehension differ from this "for" loop?

Tags: python, python-3.x, for-loop, dictionary-comprehension

I have tried implementing an algorithm with both a dictionary comprehension and a for loop, both of which I believed were set to achieve the same results.

## dictionary comprehension

```
for i in range(num_iter):
    new_state_values = {s: get_new_state_value(mdp, state_values, s, gamma) for s in mdp.get_all_states()}
```

## for loop

```
for i in range(num_iter):
    for s in mdp.get_all_states():
        new_state_values[s] = get_new_state_value(mdp, state_values, s, gamma)
```

as my algorithm runs, these achieve very different results.  Can someone point out to me where the difference lies in the two?

## Details

the full algorithm is below

```
# parameters
gamma = 0.9  # discount for MDP
num_iter = 100  # maximum iterations, excluding initialization
min_difference = 0.001  # stop VI if new values are this close to old values (or closer)

# initialize V(s)
state_values = {s: 0 for s in mdp.get_all_states()}

for i in range(num_iter):
    new_state_values = {s: get_new_state_value(mdp, state_values, s, gamma) for s in mdp.get_all_states()}

    # Compute difference
    diff = max(abs(new_state_values[s] - state_values[s]) for s in mdp.get_all_states())
    state_values = new_state_values

    if diff < min_difference:
        print("Terminated")
        break
```

the 'for-loop' version runs for barely any iterations, while the dictionary-comprehension runs for many more iterations.

**update**: the above code works and converges (and I suppose is the most pythonic, imo). The accepted answer provides good insight on the different methods.

Comment: Are you sure the `mdp.get_all_states()` is the same iterator both both loops, also I would suggest removing the `for` loop in your simplified example to see what's going on!

Comment: @DeveshKumarSingh I've got some assertion tests (given by the creator of this exercise) to test the operation of all the underlying functions.  All functions pass the assertions up until the full algorithm is run.  I think the issue is something to do with how the dictionary is being created, but maybe I've overlooked something.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The non-comprehension version accumulates values, without discarding those from the previous runs of the outer loop. If you want it to be equivalent, you'd need to change:

```
for i in range(num_iter):
    for s in mdp.get_all_states():
        new_state_values[s] = get_new_state_value(mdp, state_values, s, gamma)
```

to:

```
for i in range(num_iter):
    new_state_values = {}  # NEW!!!
    for s in mdp.get_all_states():
        new_state_values[s] = get_new_state_value(mdp, state_values, s, gamma)
```

to reinitialize `new_state_values` to a clean `dict`.

In your full code, the non-comprehension solution would leave both `state_values` and `new_state_values` as aliases of the *same* `dict` (so `state_values` would be changing as you were using it), making the problem even worse; the `dict` comprehension fixes it by building a new `dict` without modifying `state_values` as it's being built.

Comment: Thank you for your answer; I realize I made a mistake when posting here.  While trying to clear out any extraneous comments, I left out a line of code where I initialize `state_values` before the outer `for` loop begins.  I've updated it now.  Unfortunately, making these changes still results in the same behavior (that's probably because I left out a line of code in my post previously).

Comment: @Hanzy: Even after your edit, in the non-`dict` comprehension case where `new_state_values` isn't explicitly initialized to an empty `dict` each time, the moment you do `state_values = new_state_values` the two are aliasing the same `dict`, and if you don't rebind `new_state_values` to a fresh `dict` in the next loop, they stay aliases indefinitely. They were different when the loop was first entered, but they don't stay different on loops 2 and onward. Point is, your mistake was irrelevant, all that matters is `state_values = new_state_values` and whether or not `new_state_values` is rebound.

Comment: Sorry I misunderstood your meaning before.  You are correct, that does result in both methods having the same output.  Thanks for your patience, this solution was helpful.  I still can't get it to converge... but one problem down!